# Android listview overlaps edit text field when keyboard shows

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android programming so please bear with me...
I am trying to create a chat UI in android, for that I need to have an edittext field and send message button at bottom and listview (of message) at the rest of the screen (top to just above edittext and send message button). I am able to create the UI for that but when i show keyboard, the last message in listview overlaps the edittext field.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="codes.electrux.lets_start_android.PostAuthenticate">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_msg"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/msg_to_send"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="sendMessage" />



    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what happens when keyboard shows up:

[image: problem]

Here's what it looks like without keyboard:
[image: without keyboard]

I tried all solutions I could find on stackoverflow, but honestly, couldn't understand most of them.

Please help,

Thanks and Regards,

electrux.

Comment: change android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" in manifest.xml file in your activity.

Comment: set listview as layout_above property and give linearlayout id in that. also you can set specific flags in the manifest to stop resizing your screen when keyboard is open. check this link, http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try like this.**

Here your linear layout will be contains within the list view so it is overlaying last item of list. Just change as below and it will work.

**Just replace this code with your xml.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="codes.electrux.lets_start_android.PostAuthenticate">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="410dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_msg"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Send Msg" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="Send Data" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**And it's Done.**

**Hope this will help you.**

Comment: I dont understand the reason for android:layout_marginTop="5dp" even without it, the your code works perfect i think.

Comment: @Electrux Yes but i thought might be showing some space between both so layout looks good. You can remove it my purpose is just to give some space. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like the following,

Just change the list height from default to wrap_content,
And give a id to the linearLayout , make the listView to be placed above LinearLayout.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/test"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is set the ListView to match_parent widht and height.

The next, in your manifest you should declare your activity like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ConversationChatActivity"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
                  >
```

and in the activity the listView should apply this:

```
listview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
listview.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
listview.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

Hope it helps you!!